# HLSL tight packing?

Tags: c++, graphics, shader, hlsl

I have noticed that unlike GLSL, HLSL seems to pack uniforms at 4 floats even if the uniform is smaller, for example:

```
struct UBO
{
    vector<float, 2> u_screen_size;
};
```

Occupies the same memory as using 4 floats, there is no difference. Is there a way either in the syntax or the compiler to instruct it to use compact packing?